# How to detect data change in Bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

Is there any way to check if the Bootstrap-table has changed after the next ajax data load? A kind of event like this:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  onChange: function (arg1, arg2, ...) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `onLoadSuccess` success event. It Fires when remote data is loaded successfully.

[You can find the event docs here](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#onloadsuccess)

Comment: It is a pity, but onLoadSuccess only indicates the fact that the data was loaded successfully and does not contain any information indicating whether the data was changed or remains the same as before the reload.